# ASP.NET Core MVC: можно ли при submit'е формы итерироваться по её полям?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC: можно ли при submit'е формы итерироваться по её полям?

я прочитал раздел о том, как в NET Core MVC - проектах связывают поля формы и параметры вызываемого контроллера
https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.8.php

Там схема - очень жесткая: есть у тебя форма с двумя полями - её обработает метод контроллера, принимающий ровно два аргумента.

Например, вот такому View

```
    @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    }
    <form method="post">
        <label>Логин:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="login" /><br /><br />
        <label>Пароль:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="password" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
```

соответствует вот такой метод контроллера:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(string login, string password)
    {
        string authData = $"Login: {login}   Password: {password}";
        return Content(authData);
    }
```

добавил поле? аргументов в методе должно стать на один больше!

В общем то понятно, и в наиболее очевидных случаях это облегчает жизнь.

**У меня создалось впечатление, что я не могу в таком прокте написать в контроллере метод, кторый "ловит" POST от произвольной формы, и потом может итерироваться по её полям. Такая задча изредка, но возникает.**

Поверхностный гуглёж тоже не дал результатов.

Конечно, можно собрать все значения со всех полей формы в скрытое поле джаваскриптом, и одно это поле сабмитить, но как то это... overengineering.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать и обработать форму с произвольным числом полей, так, чтобы в контроллере можно было по ним просто итерироваться?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет только про параметры отправленные через форму, то можно получить доступ к ним через `Request.Form`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    foreach (var data in Request.Form)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{Key}: {Value}", data.Key, data.Value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Тогда сколько параметров передадите столько и будет. По факту, когда вы объявляете параметры в методе, то они сначала приходят в `Request.Form`, а потом уже какой-нибудь встроенный `ModelBinder` достает их из `Request.Form` и передает как обычные параметры. В коде который я привел, вы просто напряму читаете из запроса то, что пришло.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!